# How does Delayed Job work in Ruby on Rails ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to this and is little confused about how Delayed Job works ?

I know it creates a table and puts the jobs in the table and then I need to run

```
rake jobs:work
```

to start the background process. Now my question is

1. Does DJ script checks the table every minute and when the time matches job_at time, it runs that job ?
2. How it is different than cron (whenever gem) if the script is just checking the table every min ?

Thanks

Comment: !/ I guess yes 2/ it handles priorities, retry policy etc...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> 1. Does DJ script checks the table every minute and when the time matches job_at time, it runs that job ?

When you run `rake jobs:work` DelayedJob will poll the `delayed_jobs` table, performing jobs matching the `job_at` column value if it's been set. This part you're correct about.

> 2. How it is different than cron (whenever gem) if the script is just checking the table every min ?

`whenever` is a gem that helps you configure a crontab. It has nothing **directly** to do with performing tasks on your server on a periodic basis.

You *could* setup a cron to run whatever tasks exist in the queue every minute, but leaving a `delayed_job` daemon running has multiple benefits.

- Even if the cron ran every minute, `delayed_job`'s daemon will see and perform any jobs queued within that 1-minute window between cron runs
- Every time the cron would run, it will rebuild a new Rails environment in which to perform the jobs. This is a waste of time and resources when the daemon can just sit there immediately ready to perform a newly queued job.

If you want to configure `delayed_job` through a cron every minute you can add something like this to your crontab

```
* * * * * RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job start --exit-on-complete
```

Every minute, delayed_job will spin up, perform whatever jobs are ready for it or which it must retry from a previously failed run, and then quit. **I don't recommend this though. Setting up a delayed_job as a daemon is the right way to go.**

Comment: Amazing Answer Deefour, Thank You

Comment: how long can a rails delayed job be?

Answer (score 10):

> Does DJ script checks the table every minute and when the time matches
>   job_at time, it runs that job ?

yes.  It checks the database every 5 seconds.

> How it is different than cron (whenever gem) if the script is just
>   checking the table every min ?

In the context of background jobs, they are not that different.  Their main difference is how they usually run the jobs.

```
          DJ                  |            Crontab
 uses additional database     | you should either set up a rake task
 table but that's it. easier  | or a runner which can be called on the
 to code compared to crontab  | crontab
------------------------------|------------------------------------------
 requires you to run a worker | requires you to setup your cron which
 that will poll the database  | you can easily do using the whenever gem
------------------------------|------------------------------------------
 since this uses a table, it  | you have to setup some sort of logging so
 is easier to debug errors    | that you have an idea what caused the error
 when they happen             |
------------------------------|------------------------------------------
 the worker should always be  | as long as your crontab is set up properly,
 running to perform the job   | you should have no issues
------------------------------|------------------------------------------
 harder to setup recurring    | easy to setup recurring tasks
 tasks                        |
------------------------------|------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Amazing Answer jvnill, Thank You