# How to set up user onboarding emails with cron or delayed jobs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cron, actionmailer, delayed-job

I am trying to send email reminders to users who have not completed the sign-up process. The sign-up process has three different stages:

```
 1. input for interested users (this will redirect them to a registration section)
 2. registration section  (this will redirect them to set-up profile)
 3. set-up profile
```

If the user has not continued to the next stage in the process I would like to send an email reminder:

```
 1. after 18 hrs
 2. after 1 days
 3. after 4 days
```

I have heard about CRON (whenever gem) and DELAYED JOBS but don't know which one to use. And most important WHY I should choose one over the other?

Please provide an example if possible.

Answer (score 1):

I would write a script with all the logic for timing, what email to send, who to send it to etc. 
Then schedule a cronjob every 24 hours to run the script. Don't try to use the cronjobs to do the timing of how many days after to send the message.

Comment: Why did you decide to approach it using cron over delayed jobs?

Answer (score 1):

Well the reason why you would choose one over the other should be based on what you're trying to do and how you are doing it. As a developer, I would create new branches and experiment with both gems to see which one works better for you and your app.

FYI though. The whenever gem is not supported by Heroku and I believe delayed jobs is. That might be your deciding factor.

Comment: I think I can use whenever gem on Heroku. Does one perform better than the other in certain cases?

Comment: this is what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024903/how-does-delayed-job-work-in-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you write a function that checks for unfinished registrations. Then on your server, simple run a cron job every 18 hours, 1 day and 4 days (one line of script).

This cron job with call the controller that triggers the function which send reminder emails.
You could also use sidekiq as a background processor for email sending.